# request.GET.get(' ') returns None

Tags: python, django

I have the following URL: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/application_form/Network%20Adminstrator/`
The URL is generated with:  `path('application_form/<str:job_title>/', views.ApplicationForm.as_view(), name='application_form')`

I keep on trying `get_data = self.request.GET.get('job_title')` and am expecting to get `Network Adminstrator` but instead it returns **None**

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('application_form/<str:job_title>/', views.ApplicationForm.as_view(), name='application_form'),
```

]

views.py:

```
class ApplicationForm(CreateView):
    model = Requirements
    form_class = ApplicationForm
    template_name = 'requirements/job_specs.html'

    # Passes the request object to forms
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(ApplicationForm, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['request'] = self.request
        return kwargs
```

forms.py:

```
class ApplicationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request')
        super(ApplicationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        get_data = self.request.GET.get('job_title')
        print(get_data)
        dic = {'job_title__job_title': get_data}
        self.fields['qualifications'].queryset = Requirements.objects.get(**dic)

    class Meta:
        model = Applicants
        fields = ['email', 'qualifications']

    email = forms.EmailField(label='', max_length=100, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-group form-control input-lg ', 'placeholder': 'Email'}), )
    qualifications = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=None, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

Any thoughts or ideas? I am still a bit new to programing in Django and I would really appreciate your time and knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL kwargs are not in request, but in class itself. Try `self.kwargs.get('job_title')`. If it's not in your ApplicationForm, you can pass them from `get_form_kwargs` method same as you passed Request

Comment: Thanks so much, your solution worked perfectly